# Saltstack: creating Java properties file from Jinja template with arbitrary values

Tags: salt-stack

Using Saltstack (as a complete newbie), I need to deliver a Java properties file on the target. There will be a template for this file (I presumed the best template format would be Jinja) and a collection of key/value pairs to populate it. So I could do something like this:

```
/some/file/on/target:
  file.managed:
    - source:
      - salt://template.jinja
    - template: jinja
    - defaults:
      key1: value1
      key2: value2
```

The problem is that the collection is variable (over time, and from one environment to another), and the salt formula doesn't seem the best place to put its members. The salt formulas will be maintained by dev ops staff, while the properties and their values in different environments will be maintained by developers.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: My understanding of Saltstack, this kind of data would be kept in your pillar data which could be different for each environment.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would be the way to do it, but how to extract data from the pillar as a dict and pass to defaults param? I can see how to get individual values, but not the whole thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
/some/file/on/target:
  file.managed:
    - source:
      - salt://template.jinja
    - template: jinja
    - defaults:
{%- for key, value in pillar.get('default', {}).items() %}
      {{key}}: {{value}}
{%- endfor %}
```

Note the specific form of the opening tag, to suppress whitespace, otherwise it's not valid YAML. The default pillar contains e.g.:

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
.. etc.
```

Sorry to answer my own question. It really did take me that long to hit on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

While you got your own answer (right and straightforward), in practice you often need more flexibility.

### Macro Library

In few cases I used **[these Jinja macros](https://github.com/uvsmtid/common-salt-states/blob/5e8baa6b3999e46ba94dde879bb5b616473dbcce/states/common/libs/java_properties.lib.sls)** to manage Java property files:

- **[append_property](https://github.com/uvsmtid/common-salt-states/blob/5e8baa6b3999e46ba94dde879bb5b616473dbcce/states/common/libs/java_properties.lib.sls#L8)** to change "automatic part" of properties file  leaving "manual part" untouched
- **[comment_out_property](https://github.com/uvsmtid/common-salt-states/blob/5e8baa6b3999e46ba94dde879bb5b616473dbcce/states/common/libs/java_properties.lib.sls#L37)** to make sure it is unset
- **[set_property](https://github.com/uvsmtid/common-salt-states/blob/5e8baa6b3999e46ba94dde879bb5b616473dbcce/states/common/libs/java_properties.lib.sls#L60)** (force new value) while commenting out its old value

### Example

Import macro from the file in your state files and use them like this:

```
# Import one macro.
{% from 'common/libs/java_properties.lib.sls' import set_property with context %}

# State id which `set_property` below requires to complete successfully first.
unzip_application_archive:
  archive.extracted:
    - name: /tmp
    - source: salt://path/to/application.zip
    - source_hash: md5=499ae16dcae71eeb7c3a30c75ea7a1a6
    - archive_format: zip

# Call macro to render states which actually set the property.
# NOTE: It depends on the state `unzip_application_archive` above.
{{ set_property(
        'some_unique_string_for_global_state_id',
        '/absolute/path/to/file.properties',
        'property_name', 'property_value',
        [
            { 'archive': 'unzip_application_archive' }
        ]
    )
}}

# Example of state which depends on successful setting of property.
dummy_dependent_state:
    cmd.run:
        - name: 'echo DONE'
        - require:
            - cmd: set_property_some_unique_string_for_global_state_id
```

### Alternatives

- Custom **[Salt state module](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/2015.5/ref/states/writing.html)**... As of Salt version `2015.5.3` there is no standard one. Using macros above is more cumbersome (requires importing them from a file and use more cluttered syntax to call them).
- It's possible to write states directly (**[this](https://github.com/uvsmtid/common-salt-states/blob/b819961dbb683285329084952f24dab6f30d07c6/states/common/libs/java_properties.lib.sls#L21)** or **[even this](https://github.com/uvsmtid/common-salt-states/blob/5e8baa6b3999e46ba94dde879bb5b616473dbcce/states/common/libs/java_properties.lib.sls#L48)** are copy-paste-able), but it's not **[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)** enough.

At least macros above are still generically applicable for many use cases.

Comment: Thanks uvsmtid... gradually getting the hang of Salt. Serves me right for skipping the conceptual part of the documentation, as usual.